# Symfony DomCrawler get HTML without attributes / styles

Tags: symfony, domcrawler

I need a way to get a HTML from an email without attributes (class / styles).

Currently trying the following:

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addHtmlContent($mail->textHtml);

$html = '';
$nodes = $crawler->filter('body > *'); //only stuff inside body

foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    //remove somehow class+styles ?
    $html .= $domElement->ownerDocument->saveHTML($domElement);
}

echo $html; //outputs everything inside body (currently with attributes)
```

As I read on many questions already, regex is not a good solutions for something like this as it may break stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this question is from a while back, but it's still relevant, and I want to provide a solution that can help others who come across this issue.

To remove attributes (class/styles) from HTML content using Symfony DomCrawler, you can use the DOMElement's `removeAttribute` function. Here's a code snippet:

```php
foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    $domElement->removeAttribute('class');
    $domElement->removeAttribute('style');
}

$html = $crawler->outerHtml();
```

Some IDEs like PHPStorm may show a warning, "Potentially polymorphic call. DOMNode does not have members in its hierarchy". However, you can **safely** ignore this warning, and here's why:

- DOMNode is a superclass of DOMElement (subclass) and DOMElement has `removeAttribute` function.
- When you loop through the `Crawler` object using `foreach`, `$domElement` item type is `DOMNode|mixed`, but it could also be `DOMElement`. To handle this, you can use an `instanceof` check like this:

```php
if ($domElement instanceof \DOMElement) {
    $domElement->removeAttribute('style');
}
```